# How do I write a T-SQL stored proc to create primary key?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, create-table

I am trying to write a CREATE TABLE  stored proc in T-SQL.
This table should have a PK, but I want the PK to automatically seed integer values beginning from 1.  Here is the code I have currently but I am getting an error now when I try to add records.  How should I define this table instead?

Comment: Why do you want to do this inside a stored procedure?? I would do this separately, as part of my database creation script(s) - run in SSMS or SQLCMD or something - not on the fly inside a stored proc....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IDENTITY(1,1)`, i.e.

```
    CREATE TABLE myTABLE
(
  myfield bigint IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
...
...
)
```